# How do I get data from an input field into my ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, materialize

I am trying to get the data from a text field into my ajax request so that I can get a response from an API. But I have little experience with JS so I can't figure it out.

I am using the materialize framework.

HTML:

```
<div class="input-field">
    <label for="country">Autocomplete</label>
    <input type="text" id="country" class="autocomplete">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Autocomplete
    $(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/search/**{I need the text from what the user has put in here}**?token='myiextoken',
        success: function(response) {...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jquery val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method to get the input value, then you need to encode this value using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before passing it into your url.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Autocomplete
  $(function() {
    var inputValue = $('#country').val();
    var url = 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/search/'
              + encodeURIComponent(inputValue)
              + '?token='myiextoken';

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: url,
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

use `val()` to get the value of the input.

```
const value = $("#country").val();
```

and use it using [string template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Autocomplete
    const value = $("#country").val();
    $(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: `https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/search/${value}token='myiextoken`,
        success: function(response) {...
          
          */
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <label for="country">Autocomplete</label>
  <input type="text" id="country" class="autocomplete">
  <button> click </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use native JavaScript, just write:

```
document.getElementById('country').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the line

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/search/" + $('#country').val() + "?token='myiextoken'",
    success: function(response) {...
```